# For dynamically created table rows in android , onclick is invoked only after the second click?

Tags: android

I have created rows dynamically in a Table Layout.
I am setting onClickListener on the row element. But the onClick event is triggered only after the second click.

```
row = new TableRow(this);
row.setClickable(true);
row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View pView) {
    if(pView instanceof TableRow){
        TableRow lTableRow = ((TableRow) pView);
        TextView lTextView = (TextView)lTableRow.getChildAt(0);
        Toast.makeText(BusDetails.this, lTextView.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
             .show();
    }

}});
```

Any one has any idea why this is happening?

Comment: try to toast lTextView.getText().toString()..

Comment: why you are checking that if condition?